# Regular Expression in C# : Matching after a special character + specific text + till special character

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a pattern that matches everything after the special character `}` then match a text and then till first special character.

this will be clear with example.my string is like

```
string a = @"}var e=l.visible}.abc.jYOxx{margin-top:0px}.acOxx{margin-top:0px}";
```

I want to extract everything after last `}` and text matching is ".jYOxx" and then everything before first `}`.

result of my desired regex will be :

```
.abc.jYOxx{margin-top:0px}
```

I wrote this:

```
MatchCollection matchesSource = Regex.Matches(a, @"\}(.*?).jYOxx(.*?)}", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

my result is :

```
}var e=l.visible}.abc.jYOxx{margin-top:0px}
```

Logically I have a string of *css* classes and I have class name to match I want to extract that *css* class only. Please help I have wasted whole day in it.

Comment: "*matches everything after the last special character }*" - But it is not the last, its actually the second, or 3rd last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match any char except the curly brackets before matching `.jYOxx`

If you also do not want to match whitspace chars, you can add `\s` to the negated character class `[^{}\s]`

```
[^{}]*\.jYOxx{[^{}]*}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TlhJ0L/1)